# klaviyo embedded form opens in new tab when submit

Tags: email

I am using klaviyo for email listing so i have created a list on klaviyo and take the embedded form from the list and integrate it my shopify website. it needs to be submit using ajax instead of opening in new tab. but it open in new tab any help will be appreciated.

Regards.